# Magento 2.4.3 Page Builder and Porto Theme

Tags: css, magento2.4.3, page-builder

Does anyone know how I can use Porto CSS on page builder?

What I have been trying to do is that when I add a text box in page builder and I use H3 it uses its own font instead of what Porto uses for H3. Is there a way when I use page builder text box to follow css/fontstyle from proto?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using this Page Builder instead https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder It's a Free and Opening Source and also solves your problem